# Http Put Json Android

Tags: android

i try to develop an server/client app. Server is glassfish, client android(Google http api).

I use rest to transport data.

If i do a Get all is nice.

Now i want to do a Put, but i dont get my content on my server...

Client :

```
JSONObject jO = new JSONObject(json);
final HttpContent content = new JsonHttpContent(new JacksonFactory(), jO);
HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildPutRequest(url, content);
```

Server:

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JsonObject putJson(JsonObject jO, @Context HttpHeaders headers){
```

With a rest debugger (Postman), I can send some JSON to the server and get it.
Do the put with android the `JsonObject` is empty (the content debug on android is fill).

Can you help me?

Update with volley

Server:

```
    /**
 * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of Registration
 *
 * @param param1
 * @param jO
 * @param headers
 * @return 
 */
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
public JsonObject putJson(@QueryParam("email") String param1, @Context HttpHeaders headers){

    Player tmpPlayer; 
    System.out.println(param1); 
 JsonObject value = Json.createObjectBuilder()
 .add("firstName", "John")
 .add("lastName", "Smith").build();

    return value;
```

client:

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL_REGISTER, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json";
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            JSONObject tmpObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                tmpObject.put("name", "simon");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            params.put("name", tmpObject.toString());
            params.put("email", "test@test");
            params.put("password", "1234");

            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(registration);
    requestQueue.add(request);
    requestQueue.start();
```

Thanks Simon

Comment: have you filled in proper content-type http header that describes your content? (somewhere in buildPutRequest() method)

Comment: wiith  request.getHeaders().setContentType("application/json"); same problem

Comment: do you want to use volley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use Volley (Also google API)

```
String url = "http://" + URL ;
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // in case you have progressBar
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            user = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                //do something usefull 

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("volley error", error.toString());


        }
    }) {
        @Override
         public String getBodyContentType() { //override 
//  the content type because the request is string not JSON 
//   request note that if you used JSON request it will don't work with rest

            return "application/json";
        }
 //override getParams so that the server can receive the parameters otherwise 
//  parameters will be null at server  
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parameters.put("param1", myText.getText().toString());
            parameters.put("param2", myText.getText().toString());


            return parameters;
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(request);
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your replay. I try it but i dont get it:-( How i send the json? i think in the getParams its only map with string/string  on my server i dont get the json i want to send. If i say in my server i wait for a string the string is also null... How i can get the stuff on my server.

Comment: in this request your webservice should receive json and return String as json structure why you didn't get it ? have you implemented Volley lib in Gradle ?

Comment: hi, yes volley work breakpoint on my server is reached but params ar null give me a min i will update my topic what a have now

Comment: json will be sent as you did in postman the getParams() is Overriden here which you should send the param as key and value like JSON
for example, your webservice like this, public String myMethod(@QueryParam("param1")String param1){

code..
} 

in android in getParams you should do the following 
map.put("param1","any value");

Comment: public JsonObject putJson(@QueryParam("email")String param1, @Context HttpHeaders headers) ....   param1 still null with this postman dosent work...  i get a return in android but the params not on my server

Comment: same with post i get a response from server but the params on the server are null

Comment: can you show me your volley  and  webservice code ?

Comment: see at topic i post the newest server /client

Comment: i add a breakpoint in getParams() at android and i never get to this... is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `HttpURLConnection` to get the job done.

```
            URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/someAPI.php");

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            // when you are PUT do make sure you assign appropriate header
            // In this case POST.

            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            httpURLConnection.connect();

            // like this you can create your JOSN object which you want to PUT what every JON body you like to PUT
            JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
            jsonObject.addProperty("write", "whatever");
            jsonObject.addProperty("you", "want");

            // And this is how you will write to the URL
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
```

> OkHttp

this provides more elegant way of `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE`

```
GET

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    String url_String = "API url";
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url_String)
            .get()
            .build();
    okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            String response_String = response.body().string();
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: \n"+response_String);
        }
    });
```

.

```
PUT
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    String url_String = "API url";
    MediaType JSON
            = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, "JSON body to be PUT");
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url_String)
            .put(body)
            .build();
    okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            String response_String = response.body().string();
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: \n"+response_String);
        }
    });
```

Post would work similarly like PUT, you would only require to replace put method by post.

Answer (score 0):

change @Query param to @form param

Comment: get an error becaus json so i change it to application/x-www-form-urlencoded now i can work again with postman but android still not work param1 = null...    But the method getParams is never reached why? the method getHeaders is work

Comment: his is beacus i hav use jsonrequest and not stringrequest....  but with stringrequst i get now Unexpected response code 400

Comment: Don't use json request use String request and override the getContentType() as you need 
getParam method just for adding params