# Android AsyncTask is it a bad idea to use for network-purposes?

Tags: android, http, networking, android-asynctask

I've been using AsyncTasks for the past year to access a server and retrieve data, but is it a bad idea to use AsyncTasks for this purpose?

I see a lot of people using librariea such as Retrofit and others to handle their network operations.

Should I be using some third party libraries (or even Google's Volley) to handle this kind of requests?

Comment: Use Retrofit or Volley, they are better and faster, especially Retrofit with GSON.

Comment: this may help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140805/creating-a-callback-on-a-class-method/37141270#37141270

Comment: Heres really a nice answer by LOG_TAG  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley

Comment: Will give it a try to Retrofit, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Async task are basic Android way to handle task out of UI thread.

Async task have so many limitation like no orientation-change support, no ability to cancel network calls, as well as no easy way to make API calls in parallel.

With respect to networking 2 things are very important

- speed
- parallel request

`Retrofit` win in both speed and parallel network calls , `volley` is next and `Async task` is roughly **3 times slower** than `Retrofit` for single request and  **13 times slower** for 25 request.

**Clearly using  Async task is bad idea**

[image]

Image source http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/

Comment: I was already going to give Retrofit a try, but damn.. Looking at those numbers, Retrofit seems to be very quick!

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of issues with AsyncTasks such as:
No orientation, change support no ability to cancel network calls, no easy way to make API calls in parallel.

Basically it means only one AsyncTask is running at a time and it requires multiple API calls run extremely slow.

Rather us Retrofit. You can cleanly and dynamically substitute path-segments, POST/GET variables, into the endpoint and its super fast.

Comment: Didn't knew all that about AsynTasks, will give a try to Retrofit. Thanks!